# Python: fitting parameters with scipy differential_evolution, how to enforce one parameter be smaller than another one?

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

For example

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import numpy as np

def func(parameters, *data):

    a,b,c = parameters
    x,y = data

    result = (a*x**2 + b*x+ c - y)**2

    return sum(result)

bounds = [(0.5, 1), (0.5, 1), (0.5, 1)]
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([1,4,9,16,25])
args = (x,y)

parameters = differential_evolution(func, bounds, args=args,seed=np.random.seed(7))
print(parameters.x)
```

then a, b, c = [0.85699693 0.5 0.5]

Now, if some one want to enforce that c must be greater than a, i.e. c>a for the parameters fitting result. How could I achieve that?

My own solution is to use a conditional return for the defined function, so replace `return sum(result)` with `return sum(result) if c>a else np.Inf`. This gives me a new set of a, b, c = [0.83454878 0.50031474 0.83487768]

Comment: Can you reparametrize the system using a new parameter `d = c - a`, and then require `d > 0`?

Comment: Yes, this seems a good idea. Also, I think a conditional return of the function (if c<a, return a very large number) will work. Let me try that.

Comment: Basically, I tried a conditional return "return sum(result) if c>a else 100000", and then a, b, c = [0.83454878 0.50031474 0.83487768]. It seems in this case, c is enforced to be greater than a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import numpy as np

def func(parameters, *data):

a,b,c = parameters
x,y = data

result = (a*x**2 + b*x+ c - y)**2

return sum(result) if c>a else np.Inf

bounds = [(0.5, 1), (0.5, 1), (0.5, 1)]
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([1,4,9,16,25])
args = (x,y)

parameters = differential_evolution(func, bounds, args=args,seed=np.random.seed(7))
print(parameters.x)
```

[0.83454878 0.50031474 0.83487768]

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way of doing this is to use a constraint. In this case a `LinearConstraint`. The constraint you want to employ is `c - a > 0`. This solution is akin Warren's suggestion.

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
import numpy as np

def func(parameters, *data):

    a,b,c = parameters
    x,y = data

    result = (a*x**2 + b*x+ c - y)**2

    return sum(result)

bounds = [(0.5, 1), (0.5, 1), (0.5, 1)]
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
args = (x, y)

lc = LinearConstraint(np.array([-1, 0, 1]), [0], [np.inf])
parameters = differential_evolution(func, bounds, args=args, seed=np.random.seed(7), constraints=(lc,))
print(parameters.x, parameters.x[2] > parameters.x[0])
```

`[0.83546612 0.50000016 0.83546635] True`